# Implementing a global exception handler in XNA for WP7 using XNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I have a WP7 game that has symptoms similar to the following post:

[WP7 App exits when deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334614/wp7-app-exits-when-deployed)

It works fine when run through the debugger on the device, but when deployed it does not run. Also when I unplug the data connection while debugging, it runs for another 30 seconds or so and then exits!

So, I am trying to somehow trap the mysterious exception that I assume must be thrown at some point.

Question 1 
- Where can I put a try catch block so I can trap the error? Currently I have a single class derived from Game which gets executed automatically by the framework.

Question 2
- What is the easiest way to get the error message of the exception? I am using XNA so I assume a dialog box is out of the question.

Thanks!
swine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q 1.
There doesn't appear to be a way to add a global exception handler to a WP7 XNA app.
Where to add appropriate error handling will be dependent upon your code. As you haven't shown any code or even described what the app/game does it's hard to say. If you're using the data connectioion I'd look at the code you are using to make a network/web call. I would guess that you're not handling a connection dropping and you currently have a 30 second timeout on the request. Hence the applicaiton crashing 30 seconds after you disconnect from the network.

Q 2.
You can show a MessageBox from XNA. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827868.aspx

Comment: Hmmm so I've added try/catch handlers to my Draw() and Update() Game overrides, and invoked an error messages box from them (thanks for the link!). I've tested the message box on a left mouse button event, and it does show up. However, the app still exits unexpectedly without triggering my message box? I don't do any network access. It is just a game that draws a scene with a physics engine. Everything works fine as long as I'm connected to the debugger. It seems as though something times out and closes the app automatically. There is no phone setting to disable this?

Comment: Turned out to be a memory issue! No exception was thrown, but if I reduced the image sizes, the app behaved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a similar technique that we use on the Xbox 360 for Xbox LIVE Indie games. Nick Gravely shared the original sample here

http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2009/07/a-more-robust-exception-system/

and then I enhanced his to do a little more here.

http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/tellmewhatswrong/tellmewhatswrong.shtml

The same technique should work on the phone.

Comment: WP7 doesn't have a Main() to hook into, unfortunately. I think the best you can do is wrap Draw(), Update() and any other top level Game methods that might be at risk of failure.

Comment: Second link still works, and there's a link with a source code. First one is broken.